# Can I access a class variable using object of that class

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I have two very basic object oriented question

1)  Can we modify a class variable with member function?

For example

```
class test:
    '''test class'''

    idd=0
    def __init__(self,mark,subject):

        self.markk=mark
        self.subjectt=subject

    def display(self):
        print "the display is",self.markk,self.subjectt;
stud1=test(30,'maths')
stud2=test(40,'english')
```

when i tried to modify class variable idd using the object stud1.idd=9;, the variable didnt modified. test.idd=9 modified the variable.

Can someone explain me why it is not possible to modify a class vars from a object?

2) Also in the above snippet, when I added a keyword global with the class var idd like

```
class test:
    '''test class'''
    global idd;
   idd=0;
print test.idd
```

it threw error like name class test don't have attribute idd.

But when I commented out the  global idd, it displayed value.

So is global keyword not supported in class?

can someone help me to get some idea on these two question as this is my basic step to object oriented concept..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're not understanding that python looks up values by looking at a "chain" of objects<sup>1</sup>.  When you do `value = self.foo`, python will first look for `foo` on the instance.  Then it will look on the class.  Then it will look on the super-classes (in their "Method Resolution Order").

When you write:

```
self.foo = 'bar'
```

Python simply puts a `foo` on the instance.  So now subsequent lookups on that instance will give you `'bar'` even if `foo` is also defined on the class.  Also note that since `foo` gets put on the *instance*, no changes are visible on the *class*.

If you want to update the class in a particular method, you *might* be able to use a `classmethod`:

```
class Foo(object):
    idd = 0
    @classmethod
    def increment_idd(cls):
        cls.idd += 1

f = Foo()
f.increment_idd()
print(Foo.idd)
print(f.idd)
```

This doesn't work if you need access to `self` however.  In that case, you'll need to get a reference to the class from the instance:

```
class Foo(object):
    idd = 0
    def increment_idd(self):
        cls = type(self)
        cls.idd += 1

f = Foo()
f.increment_idd()
print(Foo.idd)
print(f.idd)
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>If you know javascript, it's actually not *too* much different than javascript's prototypical inheritance</sup>

Comment: any idea on second question?@mgilson

Comment: @syam -- Correct, `global` is not supported on a class.  I'm not really sure what that would do exactly ...

Comment: I have a question when i executed this.In the same code i used classmethod and i am able to modify the class var from object. But in my case i have two objects..
so when i use the 1st object to display its attr, the 2nd obj attr is displaying.

class test:
    idd=0
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self,mark,subject):
        self.markk=mark
        self.subjectt=subject
        self.idd=67;
    def display(self):
        print "the display is",self.markk,self.subjectt;
stud1=test(30,'maths')
stud2=test(40,'english')
stud1.display();-------->will display stud2's values

Comment: If i comment the @classmaker, it works as expected.
Any idea why this happens so?

Comment: When i used the @classmethod and created two objs
like ob1=class(arg)
obj2=class(arg)
then when i used the obj1 for displaying the attrs, i got obj2's attr. I meant  to say attrs of obj1 got overwritten?
when i commented  classmaker,   each objects attr displayed correctly..

example i used is same as of parent question. i used stud1.display()  to display stud1's attr. Here it displayed stud2's attr when i used  classmaker                  [stud2 obj created after stud1].   I am sorry if i am confusing you.. let me know, i can explain more

Comment: `@classmethod` makes it so that the first argument passed into the method is the class rather than an instance of the class.  Have a look at:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod -- the `@classmethod` solution that I posted only works if you don't need to have access to `self` (the instance of the class).  If you need that too, then you need to use the second method that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is a public variable you should be able to.

Comment: thanks for quick replay. Are you replying for first question?. there i can modify the class var from inside any member function outside using classname.var, but not with the object